# how to mount NAS path \\yesh\fodlername on my linux server

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mountpoint, selinux

I need to mount \yesh\fodlername NAS path on my linux server i am unable to do that using mount command, please help me over this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. Please copy and paste the exact command you tried and the output error messages you got into the question above. Then format the pasted output as code using the { } icon above the question edit window.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and on top of the above, please add the output of `lsb_release --code`.

Comment: You can replace Windows-style backslash path separators with forward slashes: see for example [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)